# Почему не видны переменные?

Tags: perl, отладка, visual-studio-code

На рисунке видно, что переменные не отображаются, с чем это может быть связано?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поставлен Perl Debug. Файл "launch.json":

```
{
    "version": "0.0.2",
    "configurations": [


    {
        "type": "perl",
        "request": "launch",
        "exec": "perl",
        "name": "Perl-Debug",
        "root": "${workspaceRoot}/",
        "program": "${file}",
        "inc": [],
        "stopOnEntry": true
    }   

    ]
}
```

Comment: У меня мелькало что-то подобное из-за проблем с `ctags`. Но могу заметить, что 1) не лучшая идея писать на Perl в VSC 2) не лучшая идея писать на Perl под Windows 3) фатальная ошибка - не начинать исходник со строк `use strict; use warnings;` или `use Modern::Perl;`...

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: Установил ctags, к сожалению не помогло. А под что и на чем лучше писать на Perl? Спасибо.

Comment: Самые суровые перловики используют vim :) Но если интересует именно IDE, то выбор небольшой: Eclipse+EPIC (мой вариант), любая IDE от JetBrains с перловым плагином, Komodo IDE (дорогущая). Какая-то поддержка перла есть в других IDE типа NetBeans, но не интересовался.

Comment: Или вот самопальный вариант, пошагово (Linux): 1) https://habrahabr.ru/post/205328/ 2) https://habrahabr.ru/post/206152/  3) https://habrahabr.ru/post/208754/